# MySQL update in a multiple join statement with only highest value from third table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, multiple-tables

(I know this could have been solved by redesigning the database, but I have already spent a lot of time researching my problem and I am hoping to learn a solution which can also be useful for later..)

I have a registration system. Users who are participants of a certain activity will be placed in the registration-table, which will be linked to the activity table, which will be linked to the weeks table, and I need to anonymize (UPDATE) the name in the users-table when the last activity the user participated in is more than four weeks old.

**My table is this:**

```
USERS
id, name

REGISTRATION
uid, aid (uid = USERS.id, aid = ACTIVITY.id)

ACTIVITY
wid (wid = WEEKS.id)

WEEKS
year, weeknumber
```

My quest is to find all USERS.id who has'nt been registered for an activity which for 4 weeks, and I which to anonymize (UPDATE) the USERS.name field in that case. So I need to select all users and through the registration-table find the activity with the latest WEEKS.year + WEEKS.weeknumber and then determine if that entry is more than 4 weeks old.

I believe I have been able to solve this as a **SELECT**, with the following statement:

```
SELECT u.id, r.act_id, a.wid, w.weeknumber, w.year
FROM users AS u 
    INNER JOIN registration AS r ON r.uid = u.id
    INNER JOIN activity AS a ON a.id = r.aid
    INNER JOIN weeks AS w ON w.id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM weeks AS w2
        WHERE w2.id = a.wid
        ORDER BY year DESC, weeknumber DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
WHERE w.year=YEAR(NOW())
AND w.weeknumber=WEEK(NOW())-5
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id DESC
```

However I am having problem converting this to a functional **UPDATE**-statement. What I have so far doesn't seem to get the latest entry from the weeks-table:

```
UPDATE users u
    JOIN registration AS r ON r.uid = u.id
    JOIN activity AS a ON a.id = r.aid
    JOIN weeks AS w ON w.id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM weeks AS w2
        WHERE w2.id = a.wid
        ORDER BY year DESC, weeknumber DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
SET u.name = 'Anonymized'
WHERE w.year=YEAR(NOW())
AND w.weeknumber=WEEK(NOW())-5
```

I would be very grateful for any pointers in the right direction as my head is spinning at this point.

Comment: Please take a llok at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  and edit your question, as you queries get mire complex, less likely it gets that someone can help you without a [mre]

Comment: Your code won't work in the first 4 weeks of the year, since 4 weeks before is a previous year.